# yii2 multiple image upload in a related model, update action how to?

Tags: php, yii2

while `actioncreate` is working fine
I am getting error when I go to update the same.

here is the code for `actionCreate`

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate1()
{
    $model = new Biodata();
    $media = new BiodataMedia();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->save();

        if ($media->validate()) {
            $images = uploadedFile::getInstances($media, 'image');
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                // $media = new BiodataMedia();
                $path = 'web/img/biodata/' . $image->basename . '.' . $image->extension;
                if ($image->saveAs($path)) {
                    $media = new BiodataMedia();
                    $media->image = $image->basename . '.' . $image->extension;
                    $media->image = '/' . $path;
                    $media->biodata_id = $model->id;
                    $media->save();
                }
            }

        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
}
```

and the code for `actionUpdate` is like this:

```
/**
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $media = BiodataMedia::find()->where(['biodata_id' => $id])->asArray()->all();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->save();
        if ($model->image == '') {
            $images = uploadedFile::getInstances($media, 'image');
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                // $media = new BiodataMedia();
                $path = 'web/img/biodata/' . $image->basename . '.' . $image->extension;
                if ($image->saveAs($path)) {
                    $media = new BiodataMedia();
                    $media->image = $image->basename . '.' . $image->extension;
                    $media->image = '/' . $path;
                    $media->biodata_id = $model->id;
                    $media->save();
                }
            }

        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model, 'media' => $media,
    ]);
}
```

the relevant `_form.php` code is like this:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\jui\DatePicker;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Biodata */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="biodata-form">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <?= $form->field($media, 'image[]')->fileInput(['multiple'=>true, 'accept'=>'image/*']) ?>       
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="text-align: center">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

The error I am getting is like:
`Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array`

Comment: You should remove `->asArray()` from query.

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: the suggestion by rob006 should work can you confirm you change the line `$media = BiodataMedia::find()->where(['biodata_id'=>$id])->asArray()->all();` to `$media = BiodataMedia::find()->where(['biodata_id'=>$id])->all();` as you need a mode instance rather than array to populate the model fild `image[]` as shown in the form

Comment: Hi Omer - yes I can confirm I modified the query as suggested by @rob006 and you removing the `asArray()` and keeping the line just as you mentioned `$media = BiodataMedia::find()->where(['biodata_id'=>$id])->all();`

Comment: that is strange can you narrow down your form to just the files input and comment out all the other active fields and confirm if you still face the same error, if yes please add the complete view `_form.php`

Comment: Hi Omer I have removed all the other fields keeping just the `fileinput` field, updated the question accordingly. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi Omer, Just an update - If I am doing like this: then I am able to get to the update page, not sure if that is correct way? like ` <?= $form->field($media[0], 'image[]')->fileInput(['multiple'=>true, 'accept'=>'image/*']) ?>` that is I have added `$media[0]`

Comment: lol :D yes you might have to use the index for the `$media` as you are returning the collection, so either you use `->asArray()->all()` or `->all()` you will have to use the index `0`. i overlooked it completely.

Comment: Hi Omer that open the update page correctly while using the index as I mentioned, but I get the same error when uploading subsequently. Also I searched everywhere there is how to for `actionCreate` or `actionUpload` but nowhere there is anything for `updaeAction`. may be I am missing something here.

Comment: i didnt quiet get what you are trying to say, are you saying that when you upload multiple files via `update` action then you get this error again after page load? also can you update your code to the latest version you have after changes.

Comment: Hi Omer, I have posted this as an answer, which I thought as the near-about solution to the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good workaround anyone looking for update action for Multiple-image upload action.
What I did is like display the existing images below the upload and adding delete button with delete action, so in a nutshell, you can remove images and add new as per your convenience.

Code in `_form.php`

```
<?= $form->field($media, 'image[]')->fileInput(['multiple'=>true, 'accept'=>'image/*']) ?>
        <?php
        if ($model->image != '') {
            foreach($model->image as $img){ ?>
            <div style="float:left">  <img src="<?=Yii::getAlias('@web');?><?=$img['image'];?>"  class="gallery img-thumbnail" style="height:150px"><br>
             <?= Html::a('<span class="btn btn-danger">Delete</span>', Url::to(['/biodata-media/delete', 'id' => $img['id']]), ['data-method' => 'POST']) ?> </div>
                <?php 
                }
        }
        ?>
```

code in `actionUpdate` controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);     

      //  $media = BiodataMedia::find()->where(['biodata_id'=>$id])->all();
        $media = new BiodataMedia();        

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {            

            $model->save();

             if($model->image !=''){
                $images = uploadedFile::getInstances($media,'image');               
                foreach($images as $image){
                $media = new BiodataMedia();
                $path = 'web/img/biodata/'.$image->basename.'.'.$image->extension;
                if($image->saveAs($path)){
                    $media = new BiodataMedia();
                    $media->image = $image->basename .'.'.$image->extension;
                    $media->image='/'.$path;
                    $media->biodata_id=$model->id;                 
                    $media->save();            
                }
               }

            }       
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }


        return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model, 'media'=>$media ]);
    }
```

Now my only issue I am facing is about the proper redirect, that is I just want to refresh the update `_form.php` on image delete, which I couldn't achieve and looking for a proper solution.